# How to get checkbox cheked value in javascript by using html dom

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, checkbox

Basically i have a list of checkbox which the data are retrieved from database and i stored it in vector to loop it. Now I need to get the value those are selected(checked) and bring it to another jsp for some purpose, may i know how can i make it ? i get "undefined" value when i alert in javascript. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

### First.jsp

```
<%
Vector vFruit_code        = new Vector();
Vector vFruit_descp       = new Vector();   

DB_FRUIT.makeConnection();
String SQL  = "SELECT * FROM TB_FRUIT WHERE TYPE='FC' WITH UR";
DB_FRUIT.executeQuery(SQL);
while(DB_FRUIT.getNextQuery())
{
    String FRUIT_CODE = DB_FRUIT.getColumnString("VALUE1");
    String FRUIT_DESCP= DB_FRUIT.getColumnString("VALUE2");

     vFruit_code.addElement(FRUIT_CODE);
     vFruit_descp.addElement(FRUIT_DESCP);
}
DB_FRUIT.takeDown();  
%>
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
 function fnCalulate()
 {

    document.getPremium.FRUIT_CODE.value    = document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE.value;
    document.getPremium.submit();

    // this part i i get undefined value when i try to alert
    alert(document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE.value);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="mainform" method="post" action="pop_fruit_route.jsp">
<table>
        <tr>
        <td>  
              <%
                for (int i=0;i<vFruit_code.size();i++)
                {
                      String sCODE = (String) vFruit_code.elementAt(i);
                      String sDESCP = (String) vFruit_descp.elementAt(i);
               %>
              <input name="FRUIT_CODE" type="checkbox" id="<%=sCODE%>" value="<%=sCODE%>" onclick="fnCalulate();"><%= sDESCP %>
          <%}%>
        </td>  
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
<form name="getPremium" method="post" action="home/calculation/calFruit.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="FRUIT_CODE">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i need to get the value from the checkbox which the items are checked to calFruit.jsp

```
String[] ID = request.getParameterValues("FRUIT_CODE");
```

output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With what you show, this will fail:

```
document.getPremium.FRUIT_CODE.value    = document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE.value;
```

because there is no FRUIT_CODE in getPremium.

If you have multiple checkboxes, you can't say `document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE.value`; FRUIT_CODE will return an array of all your fruit input tags.  you can loop over them and get the value for one that is checked, like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE.length; ++i ) {
    if (document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE[i].checked)
        document.getPremium.FRUIT_CODE.value = document.mainform.FRUIT_CODE[i].value;
}
alert(document.getPremium.FRUIT_CODE.value);
```

(though it isn't at all clear to me what you want to happen when multiple ones are checked)

or pass your function the element that was clicked, by changing the call to be:

```
onclick="fnCalculate(this)"
```

and the function to:

```
function fnCalculate(clicked_element) {
    document.getPremium.FRUIT_CODE.value = clicked_element.value;
}
```

though either way you probably want to decide what should happen when a click unchecks a checkbox.

Note that using a library such as jquery makes everything much easier.

Comment: ok what if i add <input type="hidden" name="FRUIT_CODE"> inside getPremium <form>, how should i write again in my javascript ?
database return correct result with fruit code and fruit description

Comment: i checked my console result with System.err.println("sCODE=="+sCODE);... it shows F001, F002,F003,F004

Comment: what happens for you if you get rid of everything in the `<td colspan="3">` except a hardcoded input tag like I show?  if that works but your code as it is now doesn't, something is wrong with your database code

Comment: what does the html actually delivered to the browser look like?

Comment: hi, i have uploaded the picture how the checkbox display in my screen. i even tried hardcode like what you did, yet also get "undefined" value.. hmm ... which part is wrong actually ?